# Android XmlPullParser Query

Tags: java, android, xml

Just a quick question how would I pull from a string using XmlPullParser content within a start tag?

Say the string was;

```
<location lat="56" lon="-145"></location>
```

How would I pull the lat and lon values?

Edit, is the correct way to input a string with xml content setInput(new StringReader(STRING)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this below:

```
        parser.setInput(in, "utf-8");  //in(InputStream) is your xml content stream
        int eventType = parser.getEventType();  
        while(eventType!=XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){  
            switch (eventType) {  

            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:  
                String tagName = parser.getName();  
                if(tagName!=null&&tagName.equals("location")){  
                   //This is what you want 
                   String lat = parser.getAttributeValue(null,"lat");

                }  

                break;  

            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:  
                if(parser.getName().equals("location")){  

                }  
                break;  
            default:  
                break;  
            }  
            eventType = parser.next();  
        }
```